# Prove $\forall a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z} (\exists c \in \mathbb{Z} ((a + b)c = a^2 - b^2))$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, integers

This is from the book Concrete Mathematics by Norman L. Biggs.

$$
\forall a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z} (\exists c \in \mathbb{Z} ((a + b)c = a^2 - b^2))
$$

From right hand side:
$$
a ^2 - b^2 = a^2 + ab - ab - b^2 = a(a + b) - b(a + b) \\
= (a - b) (a + b)
$$

Comparing both sides, $c$ must be $a - b$, which is also an integer (Axiom I1 indirectly applied, $a, b \in \mathbb{Z} \to (a + b) \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a - b = a + (-b)$. Although I think the axiom identifiers I1 through I7 are not standard).

$$\therefore \forall a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z} (\exists c \in \mathbb{Z} ((a + b)c = a^2 - b^2)) \text{ is true. }$$

Comment: $c$ doesn't have to be $a-b$, for instance when $a=-b$. However, $c=a-b$ certainly does work.

Comment: The statement should start $\forall a,b$, not $\forall a,b,c$. As it stands, $c$ is quantified twice, resulting in a sentence that is not well formed.